# Rails 3 - mysql returning different result than postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, math

I am trying to do some calculations in my query and i think postgresql is handling the math differently than mysql is but i'm not sure where the difference is.  This is my query from my controller:

```
Invoice.find(params[:id], :joins => :invoice_line_items, :select => "invoices.id, SUM(invoice_line_items.hours * invoice_line_items.rate) as subtotal, SUM(invoice_line_items.hours * invoice_line_items.rate) - (SUM(invoice_line_items.hours * invoice_line_items.rate) * (invoices.discount_percentage / 100)) as total", :group => "invoices.id")
```

In my development environment i am using mysql and in my production environment i am using postgresql.  These are the outputs that i am getting.  For reference, the discount_percentage is 20.

**MySQL:**

```
 |  id  |  subtotal  |  total         |
----------------------------------------
 |  21  |  570.0000  |  456.00000000  |
```

**Postgresql:**

```
 |  id  |  subtotal  |  total         |
----------------------------------------
 |  9   |  570.0000  |  570.00000000  |
```

It looks like it's something to do with the percentage and total.  Anyone have any ideas?  By the way, the MySQL result is what i am wanting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres is doing integer division.

```
Select                    MySQL   Postgres
-----------------------   -----   --------
select 999 / 100 as a     9.99    9
select 999 / 100.0 as a   9.99    9.99
```

So, change the `x / 100` to `x / 100.0` to get them both to behave the same.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for the explanation. :)  I love a quick, easy fix.